# Work Problem With Pulling A Rope

Tags: calculus

A uniform cable that is 2 pounds per feet and is 100 feet long hangs vertically from a pulley system at the top of a building (and the building is also 100 feet tall).

How much work is required to lift the cable until the bottom end of the cable is 20 feet below the top of the building?

$W=FD$

$F=2\Delta y$

$D=80-y$  ??

$\int_{0}^{100}2(80-y)dy$

Or am I mixing up the limits of integration and the distance? Or am I completely wrong? Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can't work done be represented as the change in energy of a system? Assuming metres instead of feet as the unit of measurement, the energy at the start of the system would be 200 * 50 * 10 = 100,000 J. At the end, the energy of the system would be 40 * 90 * 10 = 36,000 J. So the total work done is 64,000 J. (Gravitational potential energy is being measured here)

Comment: You have the $100$ and the $80$ transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is wrong. As you know, the total work done is given by the total force exerted over a distance. In this case the force on the cable is variable. We know that the starting weight is $200$ pounds and decreases by $2$ pounds for every foot that the cable is raised. Therefore, the force is given by $$F(x)=200-2x$$ where $x$ is the distance above the ground of the bottom of the cable. From this we get that the total work is

$$\int_{0}^{80}(200-2x) dx=9600\text{ ft lb}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can solve this problem, let's first do it in your way. Note that i'm not bothering with units. Because of feet, pound. :( not nice. Also let me note that we must talk about the $g$ (gravitation constant) because if we don't say anything about it answer wşll be no work is required.

Mass of hanging part of rope is $2(100-y)$, force acting on this part of rope is $g.2(100-y)=gm$. Work is given by $Force.Distance$. Then the integral becomes

$$ \int_0^{80}2g(100-y)\ dy = 9600$$

Another way to solve is to use energy which can be calculated easily, initial potential energy is

$$ \int_0^{100} 2gy\ dy=10000 $$

Final potential energy

$$\int_{80}^{100} 2gy \ dy + \int_0^{80} 200g dy=3600+16000 $$